# control a jack/cylinder to open/close a window

Tags: hardware, communication

I want to open the window to let the cat enter or go out, but the mecanism of the window may me think that the best way should be to use a jack/cylinder (I don't know what term is more appropriate in english for that) to open and close the door.

I will use rfid or another wireless think to know it the cat is in the place and then open the wondow but I want to close the window and let the wndow close event if there is little bit of wind, so I need domething robust.

Do you know a good hardware with (this would be the best) piece of code that can help me for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this http://www.window-openers.com/ks3040_electric_window_opener.html maybe

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-controlled-window-for-cat/) - for opening a window for a cat :)
The guy used a servo, [Towerpro MG995](http://www.servodatabase.com/servo/towerpro/mg995) with 10 kg torque for opening/closing the window, and a 10cm distance sensor for sensing the cat (he used [Pololu Carrier with Sharp GP2Y0D810Z0F Digital Distance Sensor](http://www.pololu.com/product/1134), but I believe that any proximity sensor will do).

This is a pictrure of the mechanism, seems quite robust:
[image]

Comment: I think it's safe to say that this would fall under "fair use".

Comment: so @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you woundn't recommand it? too cheap?

Comment: @clement: See the revisions of the answer.

Comment: and what about a Actuator? @Ignacio ?

Comment: Servo is a type of actuator.